# I need query to provide distinct number of choices from group of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have eight numbers in my table. I need to return 28 distinct combinations. I thought I had the code correct but it returns an infinite number of combinations.

Here is the code.

```
SELECT t1.ID AS Number_1,
       t2.ID AS Number_2,
       t3.ID AS Number_3,
       t4.ID AS Number_4,
       t5.ID AS Number_5,
       t6.ID AS Number_6
  FROM cTop8 AS t1,
       cTop8 as t2,
       cTop8 as t3,
       cTop8 as t4,
       cTop8 as t5,
       cTop8 as t6
 where t2.id <> t1.id
   and t3.id <> t2.id
   AND t3.id <> t1.id
   and t4.id <> t3.id
   AND t4.id <> t2.id
   AND t4.id <> t1.id
   and t5.id <> t4.id
   AND t5.id <> t3.id
   AND t5.id <> t2.id
   AND t5.id <> t1.id
   and t6.id <> t5.id
   AND t6.id <> t4.id
   AND t6.id <> t3.id
   AND t6.id <> t2.id
   AND t6.id <> t1.id
 ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: May start by formatting your current Select.

Comment: Infinite? Not really, just 8*7*6*5*4*3 = 20160.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` to restrict the result to 28 combinations, and `NOT IN()` to make the code more readable :

```
SELECT t1.ID AS Number_1,
       t2.ID AS Number_2,
       t3.ID AS Number_3,
       t4.ID AS Number_4,
       t5.ID AS Number_5,
       t6.ID AS Number_6
  FROM cTop8 AS t1,
       cTop8 as t2,
       cTop8 as t3,
       cTop8 as t4,
       cTop8 as t5,
       cTop8 as t6
where t1.id NOT IN(t2.id,t3.id,t4.id,t5.id,t6.id)
   AND t2.id NOT IN(t3.id,t4.id,t5.id,t6.id)
   AND t3.id NOT IN(t4.id,t5.id,t6.id)
   AND t4.id NOT IN(t5.id,t6.id)
   AND t5.id <> t6.id
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 28;
```

Comment: Can return same set of numbers but in a different order. (Take a look at Gordon Linoff's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT t1.ID AS Number_1,
       t2.ID AS Number_2,
       t3.ID AS Number_3,
       t4.ID AS Number_4,
       t5.ID AS Number_5,
       t6.ID AS Number_6
FROM cTop8 t1 JOIN
     cTop8 t2
     ON t1.id < t2.id JOIN
     cTop8 t3
     ON t2.id < t3.id JOIN
     cTop8 t4
     ON t3.id < t4.id JOIN
     cTop8 t5
     ON t4.id < t5.id JOIN
     cTop8 t6
     ON t5.id < t6.id;
```

If you want exactly 28, then you can add `LIMIT 28`.  If you want them to be random:

```
SELECT t1.ID AS Number_1,
       t2.ID AS Number_2,
       t3.ID AS Number_3,
       t4.ID AS Number_4,
       t5.ID AS Number_5,
       t6.ID AS Number_6
FROM cTop8 t1 JOIN
     cTop8 t2
     ON t1.id < t2.id JOIN
     cTop8 t3
     ON t2.id < t3.id JOIN
     cTop8 t4
     ON t3.id < t4.id JOIN
     cTop8 t5
     ON t4.id < t5.id JOIN
     cTop8 t6
     ON t5.id < t6.id
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 28;
```

Comment: You don't need the LIMIT clause. No more than 28 rows will be returned anyway. (8*7*6*5*4*3 / 6! = 28)

Comment: @jarlh . . . The number of rows returned depends on the number of different values of `id`.  I don't see that specified in the question.

Comment: "I have eight numbers in my table. I need to return 28 distinct combinations."